# K8s service could not bind automatically the corresponding endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am currently having a problem with a deployment and can't figure out the problem at this time. The problem is that the endpoints of a service are not automatically bound and the selector labels match.

**A few words about the setup:**

- Host OS: Debian 10
- Kubernetes version: 1.21
- Ingress controller: Nginx
- Firewall on the hosts of the nodes (allow list)

Furthermore, in my K8s cluster, some successful Ingress routes (different namespace) and the associated automatic endpoint assignment are already successful, so I conclude that there can't be a problem with my basic setup. In addition, I can manually enter the appropriate IP address of the pod into the endpoint and subsequently the function is guaranteed.

**Now my deployment setup:**

- Tool: Helm

**Deployment helm chart:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}-de"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}"
          image: "{{ .Values.docker.database.image }}:{{ .Values.docker.database.tag }}"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 500
          env:
            - name: LOGGING_REDIS_HOST
              value: "144.91.86.56"
            - name: LOGGING_REDIS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-sc"
                  key: LOGGING_REDIS_PASSWORD
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_NAME
              value: "{{ .Values.config.database.POSTGRES_INITDB_NAME }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: "{{ .Values.config.database.POSTGRES_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-sc"
                  key: POSTGRES_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_MONITORING_USERNAME
              value: "{{ .Values.config.database.POSTGRES_INITDB_MONITORING_USERNAME }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_MONITORING_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-sc"
                  key: POSTGRES_INITDB_MONITORING_PASSWORD
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_USER_USERNAME
              value: "{{ .Values.config.database.POSTGRES_INITDB_USER_USERNAME }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_INITDB_USER_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-sc"
                  key: POSTGRES_INITDB_USER_PASSWORD
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /storage
              name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-storage"
              readOnly: false
        - name: "{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}"
          image: "{{ .Values.docker.app.image }}:{{ .Values.docker.app.tag }}"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "250m"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 500
          env:
            - name: LOGGING_REDIS_HOST
              value: "144.91.86.56"
            - name: LOGGING_REDIS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}-sc"
                  key: LOGGING_REDIS_PASSWORD
            - name: JDBC_USER
              value: "{{ .Values.config.database.POSTGRES_INITDB_USER_USERNAME }}"
            - name: JDBC_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}-sc"
                  key: JDBC_PASSWORD
            - name: JDBC_URL
              value: "{{ .Values.config.app.JDBC_URL }}"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /storage
              name: "{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}-storage"
              readOnly: false
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "docker-registry-{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}-sc"
      volumes:
        - name: "{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-storage"
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "gluster-{{ .Values.basic.database.name }}-{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}-pvc"
        - name: "{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}-storage"
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "gluster-{{ .Values.basic.app.name }}-{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}-pvc"
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 500
```

**Service helm chart:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}-sv"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 9187
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: metrics
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: http
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
```

**Now the output of my K8s cluster:**

```
kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=sonarqube -n development
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sonarqube-de-b47bd9f75-tsbxc   2/2     Running   0          2d11h

kubectl get endpoints sonarqube-sv -n development
NAME           ENDPOINTS   AGE
sonarqube-sv   <none>      3d10h

kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=sonarqube -n development --show-labels
NAME                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     LABELS
sonarqube-de-b47bd9f75-tsbxc   2/2     Running   0          3d11h   app.kubernetes.io/name=sonarqube,pod-template-hash=b47bd9f75

kubectl get endpointslices  -n development --show-labels
NAME                       ADDRESSTYPE   PORTS     ENDPOINTS        AGE     LABELS
sonarqube-sv-fgsg2         IPv4          <unset>   192.168.202.213  3d11h   endpointslice.kubernetes.io/managed-by=endpointslice-controller.k8s.io,kubernetes.io/service-name=sonarqube-sv

kubectl get deployment sonarqube-de -n development --show-labels
NAME           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     LABELS
sonarqube-de   1/1     1            1           4d10h   app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm,app.kubernetes.io/name=sonarqube
```

Can you all help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=sonarqube -n development --show-labels` , and `kubectl get endpointslices  -n development --show-labels`?

Please note that as of Kubernetes 1.21 Endpoints are deprecated and  [EndpointSlices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/endpoint-slices/) replace them.

Thanks for including the commands you used to get the output!

Comment: Sure, I posted the output in the main post to reflect the formatting of the command.

Comment: please provide the output of kubectl get deployment sonarqube-de -n development

Comment: Deployment labels don't actually matter to services' selectors. Services only look at pods and their labels

Comment: @RakeshGupta I added the deployments' information to the main post, but I currently don't understand why this information is necessary.

Comment: @chaosaffe Do you need more information?

Comment: I've already checked the endpointslice and figured out, that the slice show no ports. I've updated it manually, and the reconcile process removed the attached ports immediately.

Comment: Is this issue resolved or are you still facing the issue ?

Comment: @SivaMannani The issue is currently not resolved and I have no idea how I can debug it. So it would be helpful if anyone can give me hints, which log I should analyse.

Comment: As it is hard to trace the root cause of this issue even with the help of provided logs, I advise you to contact (https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: @SivaMannani I'm not a user of any GCP services. I think, that makes definitely no sense to contact Google. Furthermore, I could do a further analysis of the error, if I knew where to look for the logs or which debug mode to turn on.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem by removing of the `targetPort: http` inside the service helm YAML.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}-sv"
  namespace: "{{ .Values.basic.namespace }}"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 9187
      protocol: TCP
      name: metrics
    - port: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: "{{ .Values.basic.name }}"
```